# What are the pros and cons of having assignment expressions?

Tags: expressions, assignment

Some languages (for example C and C++) have assignment expressions, which means the assignment statement as a whole returns a value of the object specified by the left operand after the assignment.

So for example in C++, [this snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/q4xrjfj4h):

```cpp
int a;
std::cout << (a = 1);
```

will print `1`.

In other languages (such as Pascal), define the assignment as a statement (meaning that it cannot be used in an expression), and there are no assignment expressions at all. Try to do `writeln(a := 1111);` and [it will return an error](https://tio.run/##K0gsTk7M0U0rSP7/vyyxSCHRSiEzryQ1PbXImispNT0zj0tBobwosyQ1J08jUcHKVsFQ05orNS9F7/9/AA).

Python takes a hybrid approach, in that it has both operators, `=` and the walrus operator `:=`, in which `:=` is an assignment expression but `=` is not, so you can do `print(a := 1)` ([link](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v6AoM69EI1HBylbBUJPr/38A)), but not `print(a = 1)` ([link](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v6AoM69EI1HBVsFQk@v/fwA)).

It's clear that each language takes a different approach to assignment expressions, so what are the pros and cons of having assignment expressions?

Answer (score 3):

### Assignment expressions can introduce bugs (when paired with implicit conversion)

For example, in C++, consider [this snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/vzE7qzq3j):

```cpp
int a = 1;
if(a = 2)
{
    std::cout << "Code in here will be executed";
}
```

It will print the code inside the `if` statement, although it's not clear as to why at first glance.

Not having assignment expressions can avoid this entire class of bugs.

Comment: I fully agree that this is a problem. But there are three factors that together lead to the problem: assignment as expression, treating integers as valid booleans, and using a very similar syntax for comparison and assignment. So, you can't blame it on assignment expressions alone.